# extracting non hidden files in shell scripting

Tags: shell

In shell scripting while listing a directory

1. need to extract non hidden files
2. need to remove upload, archive and download

example :

```
upload 
archive 
download 
simple 
data 
final
.bash_logout
.bash
```

expected output:

```
simple 
data 
final
```

Comment: What do you mean by extract? Copy to a different directory? Update your post to make it clear what you are asking (Don't put stuff like **Edit** or **Update** in your question when you do revise. This site has edit history, those who need to see differences can get the information from there.)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that by "extract" he means "remove from the list". That's sort of the definition of 'extract'. After extracting them, he wants to ignore those 3 files/directories. This isn't particularly difficult...

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the files you want using `grep`:

```
ls -a | grep -v -E '(^\.|^upload$|^archive$|^download$)'
```

The regex matches lines that begin with `.`, or are any of 'upload', 'archive', or 'download'. The `-v` flag to `grep` inverts the regex, so it'll output anything that *doesn't* match that regex.

Comment: This is why it is not a good idea to answer badly written questions: it seems that OP is working from a directory listing, not a text file...

Comment: Yeah, I don't know why I overcomplicated that. I'll replace the text file with an `ls`.